# Monaco Editor double space produces a period

Tags: autocomplete, editor, monaco-editor

I'm trying to determine what causes monaco to autocomplete a period whenever I type two spaces after a character. I've noticed this behavior even on the monaco playground, just go to the end of any line and type two spaces. *Voila*, a period appears: https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html

How can I disable this? I'm using my own custom language and even still this problem persists.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with some of your tags. Please consider updating them to reflect your issue accurately.

Comment: @AdamH I removed the JS tag, I think the rest are pertinent. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh man, this is a good one... mia culpa

This was a setting enabled in OSX and not a `monaco` editor issue. In the Keyboard section of System Preferences, just disable *Add periods with double-space* under the Text tab

https://cdn1.tekrevue.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/macos-sierra-add-period-double-space.jpg